# Securing passwords in compiled version of Windows Console application

Tags: sql-server, oracle, passwords, connection-string, app-config

In Visual Studio, I developed a simple console application that connects to several databases.  It doesn't do anything besides read from those databases to generate a bunch of folders and files on their local machine.  But I'd like to give this EXE file to other employees in our department to make their job easier.  How do I give them access to the EXE and configuration file, but secure the passwords so they cannot just connect with SQL Server Management Studio or Oracle SQL Developer?  Right now, I have the passwords clearly visible in the app.config file.

I thought about putting the passwords directly into the source code and compiling the source code and just giving them the exe, dll file, and app.config file (and others).  But I thought that could also be a risk because someone could use a tool like .NET Reflector to get those out if they had enough knowledge.

I thought about encrypting them, but I didn't know if the encrypted password strings can be used if they created their own application and used them in their own app.config in another project.  I guess I wasn't sure how they could be protected, even if encrypted.

Comment: Is there a reason that you need to use the same Oracle username and password for multiple humans using your application on multiple desktops?  The easiest answer would be to not ship the application with any credentials and simply ask the users to provide their own personal account credentials either during installation or at login time.

Comment: that would work for all but one database, which only administrators have access to

Comment: you can encrypt the connection section in the app.config.  I've actually done this, but its been some time, so try searching SO or googling for this, I'll see what I can dig up.  If this fails, try duct tape ;-)

Comment: @MacGyver - If only administrators have access to one of the databases, wouldn't they object to your application allowing additional non-administrators to connect?  If they don't object to your application allowing users to connect, why would they object to creating accounts for those users in that database with only the privileges they need to run the queries your application issues?

Comment: Because this is an auxiliary console application that helps our department for operations purposes.  The employees don't need to see this database and it wouldn't make sense for them to have direct access, because they have a Windows application (commercial tool) they use every day that connects to certain tables in this database.  This is a tool for operations.  Also, we don't have this database integrated to our Active Directory, so it would be a lot of work to restrict all users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1/ Use Windows authentication, so no user and passwords in your config file

or

2/ [Encrypt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89211k9b%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) connection string